# Script call ops can not use the redo menu？

Tags: scripting

```py
class Obj_OT_Apply_Transform(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "obj.apply_transform" 
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description=""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    # redo menu
    def draw(self, context):
        pass

class Obj_OT_Main(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "obj.main" 
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description=""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.npa.apply_transform('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        return {'FINISHED'}

# btn 1
layout.operator(
            operator='obj.main',
            text='call main'
        ) 

# btn 2
layout.operator(
            operator='obj.apply_transform',
            text='call apply'
        )
```

click `btn 2` will show redo menu, but `btn 1` shows nothing. How to do this?

### runnable example

````py
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "demo",
    "category": "zeronofreya",
    "author": "zeronofreya",
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "菜单栏 > 顶栏",
    "description": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "version": ('0', '0', '1'),
}
class Demo_PT_Eg3(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = ""
    bl_idname = "demo.eg3"
    bl_space_type  =  "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type  =  "UI"
    bl_category = "DemoEg"  # tab name

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text='show redo menu')
        self.layout.operator(
            operator='demo.eg',
            text='call ops'
        )
        self.layout.label(text='not show redo menu')
        self.layout.operator(
            operator='demo.eg2',
            text='script call ops'
        )
        
class Demo_OT_Eg(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "demo.eg" 
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description=""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, 'run eg')
        print('run eg')
        return {'FINISHED'}   
    
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text='redo menu')

class Demo_OT_Eg2(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "demo.eg2" 
    bl_label = ""
    bl_description=""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.demo.eg('EXEC_DEFAULT')
        return {'FINISHED'}     

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Demo_OT_Eg)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Demo_OT_Eg2)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Demo_PT_Eg3)
    

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Demo_PT_Eg3)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Demo_OT_E2)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Demo_OT_Eg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: you need `bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}`  in the class definition and either a custom `draw` method and / or a custom property annotation definition for the undo / redo panel to appear

Comment: @Gorgious Thank you, but I have added UNDO and draw, how does the custom property work? Can you tell me in detail?

Comment: Could you update the code in your question ? seems like it's missing something. You're calling operators that you didn't provide the definition for. (`npa.apply_transform` and `npa.main`)

Comment: @Gorgious Sorry for my typo, npa has been changed to obj. Do I need to provide a complete example? But that will only add the ui part?